# ¿Como enviar un datatable en un array SqlParameter[] hacia un WebMethod de un WebService?

Tags: c#, webservice

Necesito enviar un Datatable junto a otros parametros dentro de un  `SqlParameter[]` hacia un WebService pero devuelve el error:

**`{"El tipo System.Data.DataTable no se puede utilizar en este contexto. Para usar System.Data.DataTable como parámetro, tipo de valor devuelto o miembro de una clase o struct, el parámetro, tipo de valor devuelto o miembro debe declararse como tipo System.Data.DataTable (no puede ser un objeto). Los objetos de tipo System.Data.DataTable no se pueden usar en colecciones sin tipo, como ArrayLists."}`**

el webmethod:

```
 [WebMethod]
    public int ProcesaTablaWS(List<SqlParameter> parametros, ref string error)
```

Como consumo del webmethod:

```
public DataSet Envia_Tabla(DataTable dt, ref string error)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        List<SqlParameter> li = new List<SqlParameter>();
        li.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@tabla", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured, Value = dt });
        li.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@nombre", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Varchar, Value = "campos"});
        
        SqlParameter[] parametros = li.ToArray();
        ds = ws.ProcesaTablaWS(parametros, ref error);
        

        return ds;
    }
```

¿Alguna alternativa o solución? La idea es que el el webmethod sea reutilizable, así que no quiero enviar el *Datatable* como parámetro.

Comment: `li.Add(new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@tabla", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured, Value = dt });` Ahí te salta el error?

Comment: No, sale el error cuando lo envio al ws. en: `ds = ws.ProcesaTablaWS(parametros, ref error);`

Comment: Y si lo cambias por ws.ProcesaTablaWS(li,ref error)... te salta error?

Comment: no me acepta el parametro. si bien el ws dice List<SqlParameter> Al agregarlo como referencia me pide un SqlParameter[]